# Dynamically calculate status in MLM

Tags: python, beginner, performance, django

Problem: dynamically calculate status in MLM only based on a structure.

It works correctly but it's so slow. Only test processing takes about 20 seconds. I tried to replace some lists by generators, but it was bad solution, because they have to be changed during runtime. I have no more ideas of enhancements but I'm sure that code is so ugly and optimizible. The main logic is in the last function.

```
@property
def consultants_at_first_two_lines(self):
    return self.first_line.filter(consultant_experience=True) | self.second_line.filter(consultant_experience=True)


def golden_club_bonuses(self, start_date, end_date):
    status = self.golden_club_status_on_date(date.today())
    result = status.bonuses
    if start_date:
        result = filter(lambda x: x.bonus_date >= start_date, result)
    if end_date:
        result = filter(lambda x: x.bonus_date <= end_date, result)
    return result

def executed_in_period(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    result = TreeNode.objects.filter(executor=self).order_by('contract_date')
    if start_date:
        result = result.filter(contract_date__gte=start_date)
    if end_date:
        result = result.filter(contract_date__lte=end_date)

    return result

def invited_in_period(self, start_date=None, end_date=None):
    result = self.children.order_by('contract_date')
    if start_date:
        result = result.filter(contract_date__gte=start_date)
    if end_date:
        result = result.filter(contract_date__lte=end_date)
    return result

def golden_club_status_on_date(self, status_date):
    step = timedelta(days=1)

    if self.invited_in_period():
        enter_period_start = self.invited_in_period()[0].contract_date
    else:
        enter_period_start = None

    if enter_period_start:
        current_date = enter_period_start
    else:
        current_date = self.contract_date + step
    prev_rank = None
    current_rank = 0
    next_rank = 0
    invited = []
    executed = []
    rank_apply_date = None
    bonuses = []
    while current_date <= status_date:
        if enter_period_start and enter_period_start + time_settings['golden_club_enter_period'] < current_date:
            enter_period_start = None
        if rank_apply_date == current_date:
            if not self.consultant_experience and next_rank:
                TreeNode.objects.filter(id=self.id).update(consultant_experience=True)
            if current_rank == 1:
                for newbie in executed:
                    bonus = GoldenClubBonus(executor=self,
                                            executed=newbie,
                                            total=golden_club_awards['consultant_executing'],
                                            bonus_date=current_date)
                    bonuses.append(bonus)
            elif current_rank == 2:
                for newbie in invited:
                    bonuses.append(GoldenClubBonus(executor=self,
                                                   executed=newbie,
                                                   total=golden_club_awards['senior_consultant_executing'],
                                                   bonus_date=current_date))
                my_consultants = self.consultants_at_first_two_lines.all()

                grandsons = [child.executed_in_period(start_date=(current_date-timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1),
                                                      end_date=current_date-timedelta(days=1)) for child in (cons for cons in list(self.consultants_at_first_two_lines)
                            if cons.golden_club_status_on_date(status_date=date.today()).prev_rank)]

                for x in my_consultants:
                    if x.golden_club_status_on_date(current_date - step):
                        for grandson in x.executed_in_period(start_date=(current_date - step).replace(day=1),
                                                            end_date=current_date - step):
                            grandsons.append(grandson)
                for grandson in grandsons:
                    bonuses.append(GoldenClubBonus(executor=self,
                                                   executed=grandson,
                                                   total=golden_club_awards['senior_consultants_son_executing'],
                                                   bonus_date=current_date))
            prev_rank = current_rank
            current_rank = next_rank
            next_rank = current_rank - 1 if current_rank > 0 else 0
            del invited[:]
            del executed[:]
        for x in self.invited_in_period(start_date=current_date, end_date=current_date):
            if not (enter_period_start or current_rank or next_rank):
                enter_period_start = current_date
            invited.append(x)
        for x in self.executed_in_period(start_date=current_date, end_date=current_date):
            executed.append(x)

        if current_rank == 0:
            if next_rank == 0 and \
               enter_period_start and  \
               len(self.invited_in_period(start_date=enter_period_start,
                                          end_date=enter_period_start + time_settings['golden_club_enter_period'])) >= 10:
                next_rank = 1
                enter_period_start = None
        elif current_rank == 1:
            if next_rank == 0 and (len(invited) >= 5 or len(executed) >= 10):
                next_rank = 1
            if next_rank == 1 \
                    and (len(invited) >= 5 or len(executed) >= 20) \
                    and len(self.consultants_at_first_two_lines) >= 3:
                next_rank = 2
        elif current_rank == 2:
            if next_rank == 1 and (len(invited) >= 5 or len(executed) >= 20):
                next_rank = 2
        rank_apply_date = next_nth_day_of_month(date1=current_date, n=1, include_today=False)
        current_date += step
    result = GoldenClubStatus(prev_rank=prev_rank,
                              current_rank=current_rank,
                              next_rank=next_rank,
                              bonuses=bonuses,
                              enter_period_start=enter_period_start,
                              rank_apply_date=rank_apply_date,
                              status_date=status_date,
                              invited=self.invited_in_period(),
                              executed=self.executed_in_period(),
                              owner=self)
    return result
```

Comment: Try [profiling](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html) to see where the 20 seconds is spent.

Comment: What is an MLM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two trivial things:

```
if start_date:
    result = filter(lambda x: x.bonus_date >= start_date, result)
if end_date:
    result = filter(lambda x: x.bonus_date <= end_date, result)
```

should be

```
if start_date:
    result = (x for x in result if x.bonus_date >= start_date)
if end_date:
    result = (x for x in result if x.bonus_date <= end_date)
```

Also,

```
grandsons = [child.executed_in_period(start_date=(current_date-timedelta(days=1)).replace(day=1),
                                      end_date=current_date-timedelta(days=1))
                for child in (cons for cons in list(self.consultants_at_first_two_lines)
                if cons.golden_club_status_on_date(status_date=date.today()).prev_rank)]
```

should just be

```
day = timedelta(days=1)
today = date.today()
yesterday = current_date - day
yesterday_dayeq1 = yesterday.replace(day=1)

grandsons = [child.executed_in_period(start_date=yesterday_dayeq1, end_date=yesterday)
                for child in self.consultants_at_first_two_lines
                if child.golden_club_status_on_date(status_date=today).prev_rank]
```